# Django REST authentication from desktop app

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication

I have been trying to use the Django-REST authentication to validate the user name /password given in a desktop app.

On the server side, I have installed the following DJANGO-REST-FRAMEWORK-JWT package found here:

```
https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt
```

I have gone through the example and when I run the following on the command line  get a token as a response:

```
curl -X POST -d "username=luca&password=letmein123" http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/
```

And I get:

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InBhbmthaiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjIsImVtYWlsIjoiIiwiZXhwIjoxNDc5MTE5NzQ2fQ.RA085m-YSnGFheykCCxSVxI_9rW9AC9kEaOkUB5Gm0A"}
```

I tried something like:

```
import requests
resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/', data={}, auth=('luca', 'letmein123'))
```

However, this always returns response code `400` with `Bad request`

My question is how can I do that from my desktop python app. I basically want to call the same API with the username and passord and be able to process the response and access protected APIs.

Comment: Did you try just passing in a dictionary as params={'username':'luca', 'password':'letmein123'}

Comment: @aris Ok, I got it working by doing: `resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/', data={'username': 'luca', 'password': 'letmein123'})`

Comment: This is how I post to DRF using curl: `curl -X POST --data 'foo=42&bar=17' -H 'Authorization: Token 6fae00e2d44b3da2e7fd31ff24c1d79637f47e68' http://example.com:666/rest/TempHumiditySample/`

Answer (score 0):

The `auth` parameter of [requests.request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#main-interface) is by default meant for Basic/Digest/Custom HTTP Auth, analogous to the `-u, --user <user:password>` parameter of curl.
You could [define your own custom Authentication class](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-authentication) to achieve the desired result, but the basic way to achieve the same result as your original curl request is:

```
resp = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/',
    data={"username": "luca", "password": "letmein123"})
```

The `data` dictionary can alternatively be supplied as json by using the `json` parameter if you prefer (the request would be different, but [also supported](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage) by Django REST framework JWT).

You can then use the token (extracted with `token = resp.json()['token']`) to access the restricted urls as following:

```
requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/some-personal-function/',
    json={"foo": 42},
    headers={'Authorization': 'JWT ' + token})
```

By the way looking at `response.text` might help finding the reason, which would, in the case of your `400` response, contain the following:

> '{"username":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."]}'